# Is there a way to replace the value in one column with the value from another column and then 'blank' out the value taken to replace?

Tags: r, replace

I have the data frame pictured below.  What I am trying to do is in the case where '2nd_Booking_Deadline' column is blank ("") then replace it with the value in '3rd_Booking_Deadline'. Once '2nd_Booking_Deadline' is replaced with the value from '3rd_Booking_Deadline' I need to blank ("") out '3rd_Booking_Deadline.

I have written the below piece of code that sees to accomplish the 1st part of that task but it returns a warning that makes me a bit nervous:

```
Warning message:
In AAR_Combined_w_LL$`2nd_Booking_Deadline`[AAR_Combined_w_LL$`2nd_Booking_Deadline` ==  :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Here is what I have come up with so far:

```
AAR_Combined_w_LL$`2nd_Booking_Deadline`[AAR_Combined_w_LL $`2nd_Booking_Deadline` == ""] <- AAR_Combined_w_LL$`3rd_Booking_Deadline`
```

Any thoughts on if that warning is serious and if there is a way to complete both tasks at the same time would be super helpful[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While replacing you need to subset from both the ends. Try :

```
#Get the indices where `2nd_Booking_Deadline` is blank
inds <- AAR_Combined_w_LL $`2nd_Booking_Deadline` == ""

#Replace those blank values from the corresponding indices
AAR_Combined_w_LL$`2nd_Booking_Deadline`[inds] <- AAR_Combined_w_LL$`3rd_Booking_Deadline`[inds]

#Change `3rd_Booking_Deadline` to blank string
AAR_Combined_w_LL $`3rd_Booking_Deadline`[inds] = ""
```

Comment: oh wow - that works perfectly - thank a ton.  I hadn't considered the indices approach.